# Hover com dois efeitos: aumentar e diminuir width de divs diferentes

Tags: html, css

Eu possuo 5 `divs` formando uma coluna.
Quero que quando eu passe o mouse sobre uma das colunas essa coluna aumente a largura em 4% e as demais passe a ter o tamanho de 19%, causando um efeito de sanfona.

Eu consegui fazer com jQuery, porém ele tem um *delay* no primeiro uso, fazendo com que "pisque" a imagem quando sobreposto o mouse.

Já tinha notado esse tipo de falha em um outro projeto, mas nesse não estou achando uma solução com CSS para resolver.

```js
$(".col").mouseleave(function(){
    var largura = $(document).width();
    if(largura>420){
        $(this).css("-webkit-transition","300ms");
        enter = $(this).attr("class");
        $(".col").each(function (){
            if($(this).attr("class") != enter){
                $(this).css("width","20%");
            }
        });        
        $(this).css("width","20%");
        $(this).css("filter","grayscale(100%)");
    }
});
$(".col").mouseenter(function(){
    var largura = $(document).width();
    if(largura>420){
        $(this).css("-webkit-transition","900ms");
        $(this).css("filter","grayscale(0%)");
        enter = $(this).attr("class");
        $(".col").each(function (){
            if($(this).attr("class") != enter){
                $(this).css("width","19%");
            }
        });        
        $(this).css("width","24%");
    }
});
```

```css
.col{
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 678px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.col-vestibular{
    background-image: url(../img/PSP-1366.png);
    background-size: auto 768px;
    /*adicionado para faciltar a visualização*/
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.col-enem{
    background-image: url(../img/PSP-1366.png);
    background-size: auto 768px;
    /*adicionado para faciltar a visualização*/
    background-color: #c3c;
}
.col-transferencia{
    background-image: url(../img/PSP-1366.png);
    background-size: auto 768px;
    /*adicionado para faciltar a visualização*/
    background-color: #cc3;
}
.col-segunda-graduacao{
    background-image: url(../img/PSP-1366.png);
    background-size: auto 768px;
    /*adicionado para faciltar a visualização*/
    background-color: #3cc;
}
.col-pos-graduacao{
    background-image: url(../img/PSP-1366.png);
    background-size: auto 768px;
    /*adicionado para faciltar a visualização*/
    background-color: #c33;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
   <div class="col col-enem" style="width: 20%; transition: 300ms; filter: grayscale(100%);">
      
   </div>
   <div class="col col-vestibular" style="width: 20%; transition: 300ms; filter: grayscale(100%);">
      
   </div>
   <div class="col col-segunda-graduacao" style="transition: 300ms; filter: grayscale(100%); width: 20%;">
   </div>
   <div class="col col-transferencia" style="width: 20%; transition: 300ms; filter: grayscale(100%);">
      
   </div>
   <div class="col col-pos-graduacao" style="width: 20%; transition: 300ms; filter: grayscale(100%);">      

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Porque não usas o pseudo-elemento hover? Fiz um [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u8hu07w/) de exemplo bem básico.

Comment: O problema é que eu preciso crescer esse elemento e reduzir o tamanho dos demais com o mesmo efeito do hover, entende?

Comment: Testei aqui e não pisca não. Dá um saque: https://jsfiddle.net/a23Lvnmc/

Comment: É possível fazer isso apenas com CSS, pseudo elemento hover e flexbox. Dá uma lida em flexbox que é bem facinho.

Comment: Uma outra dica, seria pre-carregar a imagem, só não sei se funciona com eficiência: `body::after{position:absolute;width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden;z-index:-1;content:url(../img/PSP-1366.png);}
`

Comment: Olha esse pen: Vai te salvar: https://codepen.io/dsantoro/pen/mpyjMb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de usar `background-image`, você pode inserir a imagem que usa de `background` como `<img>` dentro de cada `div`, usando [object-fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) para preencher toda a `div`. Isso pode evitar o "pisca" mencionado.

Além do que, seu código possui muita redundância, tanto no CSS quanto no jQuery. 
Veja abaixo um exemplo com o código otimizado, com significativa redução de conteúdo:

```js
$(".col").each(function(){
   $(this).append("<img src='https://jpeg.org/images/jpeg-home.jpg' />");
});

$(".col").on('mouseleave mouseenter',function(e){
    var largura = $(document).width();

   if(largura>420){
      if(e.type == "mouseleave"){

         enter = $(this).attr("class");
         $(".col").not($(this)).each(function (){
               $(this).css("width","20%");
         });        
         $(this).css({
            "-webkit-transition" : "300ms",
            "width" : "20%",
            "filter" : "grayscale(100%)"
         });

      }
      
      if(e.type == "mouseenter"){
         enter = $(this).attr("class");
         $(".col").not($(this)).each(function (){
               $(this).css("width","19%");
         });        
         $(this).css({
            "-webkit-transition" : "900ms",
            "width" : "24%",
            "filter" : "grayscale(0%)"
         });
      }
   }

});
```

```css
.col{
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 678px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    /*adicionado para faciltar a visualização*/
    background-color: #ccc;
    background-size: auto 768px;
}

.col img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   object-fit: cover;
   object-position: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="col col-enem" style="width: 20%; transition: 300ms; filter: grayscale(100%);">
   </div>

   <div class="col col-vestibular" style="width: 20%; transition: 300ms; filter: grayscale(100%);">
   </div>

   <div class="col col-segunda-graduacao" style="transition: 300ms; filter: grayscale(100%); width: 20%;">
   </div>

   <div class="col col-transferencia" style="width: 20%; transition: 300ms; filter: grayscale(100%);">
   </div>

   <div class="col col-pos-graduacao" style="width: 20%; transition: 300ms; filter: grayscale(100%);">      
   </div>
</div>
```

> O [object-*](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) não é compatível com o famigerado IE.

Answer (score 2):

Ainda assim é possível não fazer uso de Javascript para isto, utilizando somente [layout flexível](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). O único ponto importante a ser considerado é a questão do [suporte da propriedade](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), porém como nada foi mencionado na pergunta deixo aqui como uma possível solução.

- [Um guia completo para Flexbox <sup>(en)</sup> no CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

A ideia é utilizar um [`display: inline-flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) no elemento que será o "container" dos `<div>` que irão se expandir. Assim você deixa que o controle de largura seja feito automaticamente. Então pode utilizar a [sugestão do Marconi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262728/hover-com-dois-efeitos-aumentar-e-diminuir-width-de-divs-diferentes#comment538803_262728) de, somente aumentar o valor do `width` no evento de `:hover`:

```css
/* No caso, meu "container" é o próprio body. */
body { display: inline-flex; width: 100% }

div {
  height: 100%;
  transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
  width: 20%
}

div:hover {
  width: 30%
}

div:nth-child(1) { background: #7BB0A6 }
div:nth-child(2) { background: #63393E }
div:nth-child(3) { background: #97CE68 }
div:nth-child(4) { background: #FACA9B }
div:nth-child(5) { background: #897FBA }

/* Regras não relacionadas, servem somente p/ melhorar aparência do snippet. */
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
html, body { height: 100% }
```

```html
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
<div>d</div>
<div>e</div>
```